# What are the basic open sets of $(\{0\}\cup\{1/n\})^{\mathbb N}$?

Tags: general-topology

I am thinking that the basic open sets look something like,

$$\{1/3\} \times \{1/5\} \times (\{0\}...\cup\{1/1523\} \cup \{1/1522\}) \times \{1/10\} \times \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \times ...$$

But there are two things I'm unsure of.

1. When, in the product topology, can we take the basic open sets to be listed in the 1st n slots and then the whole space afterwards, and when can it not be done?
2. I am also confused about whether we can just take the basic open sets to be of the form $\{1/3\} \times \{1/5\} \cup \{1/1522\}) \times \{1/10\} \times \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \times ...$, i.e. without the open sets around $\{0\}$.

Comment: Is the $n$ in the fraction fixed? Perhaps you could write the statement in full inside the question text.

Comment: No, it should read $\{1/n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can always form a base for any product space consisting of basic open sets in a finite number of slots and the whole space elsewhere.  But in your case the whole space is not ${\bf N}$ but $X:=(\{0\}\cup\{1/n\}_n)^{\bf N}$, so writing $\cdots\times{\bf N}\times{\bf N}\times\cdots$ is not right.

The set $$\{1/3\}\times\{1/5\}\times(\{0\}\cup\cdots\cup\{1/1523\}\cup\{1/1522\})\times\{1/10\}\times X\times X\times\cdots$$ forms indeed a basic open set, although the notation seems strange to me, I'd write $[0,1/1522]\cap X$ or something for the middle factor.

And no, you need open sets around zero for your base, otherwise the union of your base sets wouldn't equal $X$, which is condition for any base.